# Monitor remote DD operation and display progress

Tags: bash, ssh, centos, dd

Let me preface this by saying "I am not a programmer".

I have a script that I execute to create free space on storage arrays during testing. The script works as designed, however I am having issues monitoring the progress. I execute the script from a host (master). The host executes a DD command on workers in the background. Each worker has multiple SDs defined. The command structure is like this:

```
ssh root@worker1 dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1G count=256 &
ssh root@worker1 dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1G count=256 &
ssh root@worker2 dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1G count=256 &
ssh root@worker2 dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1G count=256 &
ssh root@worker3 dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1G count=256 &
ssh root@worker3 dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1G count=256 &
ssh root@worker4 dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1G count=256 &
ssh root@worker4 dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1G count=256 &
```

This approach works great, and I get excellent write throughput on my back end storage. The problem is that I need to know when these processes are complete. When they finish, I need to execute the next phase of my testing.

Ideally I need a way to continuously monitor the DD process on the workers and provide progress. When they are all finished, the script would exit and the next phase of testing should begin.

Update***

I switched from using DD and am now using blkdiscard. It is much faster for what I am trying to do. The new command structure looks like this.

```
ssh root@worker1 blkdiscard -o 256G -l 256G -p 1G /dev/sdb &
ssh root@worker1 blkdiscard -o 256G -l 256G -p 1G /dev/sdc &
```

In case this helps anyone else.

Comment: Use `wait` in your script after listing all cmds in a group that can run together. The script will then `wait` until all background jobs are complete, before moving onto the next step in your script. For your code as above, just add `wait` after the last `ssh ...` line. And pluse-uno for Q that is better than many submitted by "programmers" ;-)  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, adding wait works and it moves on when finished. The problem is that users are sitting there staring at a black screen and no idea that anything is happening. Is it possible to add wait to a loop so that while it's waiting it could echo a repeating message or progress bar of sorts?

Comment: I'm testing an idea. Back in a few.

Comment: I think I got it. Added above.

Comment: Glad you solved it. I had tried a basic `while wait` loop, and it never exited. But I use `ksh`, so that might be different. Pretty darn good for "I am not a programmer". (Reminds me of Steve Segal, "I'm just the cook") . Post your solution as an answer and you can accept your answer after 48 hrs for valuable reputation points. Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't got it. I forgot to put my command in the background so wait didn't have anything to do. Now that the command is running it never gets to the loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101717/discussion-between-steve-kehrer-and-shellter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue thanks to @shellter and another post I found. Instead of wait, I am using the process ID of the previous running command.

```
#Execute blkdiscard on workers via remote SSH
ssh root@worker1 blkdiscard -o 256G -l 256G -p 1G /dev/sdb &
ssh root@worker1 blkdiscard -o 256G -l 256G -p 1G /dev/sdc &

# Process Id of the previous running command
pid=$!

# Spinning cursor string
spin='-\|/'

i=0
while kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null
do
    # Progress message
    echo -ne "\033[2K\rPreparing array for snapshot testing ";

    # Spinning cursor on same line
    i=$(( (i+1) %4 ))
    echo -ne "${spin:$i:1}"
    sleep .1
done
```

Then end result is the message: Preparing array for snapshot testing with a spinning cursor at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you add double ampersand at the end of commands next written command will start after first one is finished.

example:

```
echo something && sleep 5 && echo anotherthing &
```